# The named parameter 'builder' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.Try adding the required argument

Tags: flutter, dart

I Got This Weird Error:

"The named parameter 'builder' is required, but there's no corresponding argument."

*Anyone know it then pls Help me*

````
@override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text("Register"),
      ), 
    body:FutureBuilder(
      future: Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultfirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
        );
    builder: (context,snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.done:```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your snippet I can see a syntax error:

```dart
...
FutureBuilder(
  future: Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultfirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  ); // HERE, YOU SHOULD PUT A `,`
  builder: (context,snapshot) {
    ...
  }
...
```

Putting a `;` there breaks the code analysis, which is why it tells you "Hey, I'm expecting a `builder` parameter there". The code should also expect you to write a `,` instead.